# I cant host my laravel project on a free hosting site

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

I'm already done with my project in Laravel but when I try to host it on 000webhost it shows me

> coindeorotest.000webhostapp.com is currently unable to handle this
>   request. HTTP ERROR 500

I already followed the instructions here https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/code-error-500-on-laravel-projects/127667/11 but it keeps me getting an error. I already migrated the databases in my project. Can someone help?

database.php

```
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'id10201702_adminpanel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'id10201702_root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '12345'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', 'localhost'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
            'database'  => env('id10201702_ricjac8_orocoin'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'id10201702_root2'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD','12345'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HoQcNyCc5KEGw4yjqpBIdKzTC+yeDoOJcerVMEVx+fs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=true

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id10201702_adminpanel
DB_USERNAME=id10201702_root
DB_PASSWORD=12345

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql2
DB_HOST_SECOND=localhost
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=id10201702_ricjac8_orocoin
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=id10201702_root2
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=12345
```

Comment: a 500 error can mean literally anything. Having some experience with laravel though, its most likely that some folders dont have the right read/write permissions.

Comment: do you have any idea how could I fix that error sir?

Comment: Is the storage folder writable? Look if there are any logs in `storage/logs/`, these might help you further.

Comment: Why you not using Heroku instead ?

Comment: is Heroku free to use sir? @Ivan

Comment: I have logs in the `storage/logs/` but these logs are the old ones when I was developing my project sir.

Comment: @Vince Yep, it's free to use. Find out here [Heroku Price](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)

Comment: okay sir thanks.. I will now try to host my laravel using heroku.